# Force autocomplete="off" on whole HTML document

Tags: html, autocomplete

Is there a way to set `autocomplete="off"` as standard behaviour to **every element** on the whole HTML document **at once**? (I am not looking for a way to do this for a single element)

I am searching for an easy solution, maybe similar to how cache-control in the HTML header works. It does not have to be secure (if someone wants to somehow re-enable autocomplete that's fine), I just want it as default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this using jquery. Try below -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
     $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
   });
});
```

**OR** you can try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

The browser autocomplete is unrelated to the browser cache. The cache saves the actual data sent to the browser by web sites - i.e. the HTML code, CSS, Javascript and images. The autocomplete is a browser feature that saves what the user types into forms.

Setting "no-cache" will not stop autocomplete, it will just stop the browser saving the page to the user's computer. If the page itself contains possibly sensitive information (outside of the form), then use it, otherwise it the user must download the page every time they visit it, using more bandwidth for them and the server.