# Turn off autoComplete for all inputs in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062076/1265071) explains how to turn off `autocomplete` for an entire HTML document with *jQuery*.

Without jQuery is there a way to turn "off" React's equivalent `autoComplete` for all inputs within the app?

*I'm not very familiar with jQuery otherwise I'd try to convert the function myself.*

Answer (score 11):

To disable the autocomplete for input fields in React, we need to set the input field’s autoComplete attribute to "new-password".

```html
<input type="email" name="email_signup" placeholder="Email" autoComplete="new-password" />
<input type="password" name="password_signup" placeholder="Password" autoComplete="new-password" />
```

This will turn off autocomplete for input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `autocomplete="off"` on the parent level of the form and that will turn it off for the entire form

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[…]
</form>
```

Comment: wrapping my entire topmost component in this (specifically just `<form autocomplete="off">`) did the trick as long as all other inputs were not wrapped in another `form`

Comment: never mind... breaks other things within my app for some reason

Comment: You can read about that here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 2):

use this in elements:

```
autoComplete:'off'
```

Comment: Could you clarify how your answer is substantially different than the [top scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57482995/) of this question?

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours investigating all the solutions, I have found one using this CSS properties here:

```
-webkit-text-security: disc;
```

Change your text input filed type back to a normal text field so the browser won't suggest the autofill and use this css properties to make it act like a "Password Input field". It has 96% of browser supported and I think this will be the best approach so far

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with

```
<input name="myinput" placeholder="enter your name" value={this.input.myinput} autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The post that you are linking is just assigning the autocomplete off attribute to the document when it is loading. You can accomplish what jQuery is doing with something like the following using vanilla JS. However, I would suggest a more "React" way of doing things based on whatever logic you wish to accomplish.

```
var foo = document.querySelector("input"); 
foo.setAttribute("autoComplete", "off");
```

Comment: where would you suggest placing this? I've tried in my top-most component with little success

Comment: It wouldn't work on the topmost level since the attributes would be set when `setAttribute` is called. Where the placement belongs depends on where the inputs are being rendered. If it's more than one input, you'll need `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByTagName` and iterate over the nodes in the list, setting the attribute. This will set the assignments to the input fields when that component re-renders.